# AVR C++ uint32_t weird behaviour

Tags: c++, avr

```
uint32_t a = 65536;
uint32_t b = 1 << 16;
```

Why is `a != b` here, but

```
uint32_t a = 65536;
uint32_t b = 65536;
```

here `a == b` although it should technically be the same?

I'm using CLion as an IDE and CMake 3.7.1 with Arduino CMake.

Comment: Am I right to assume this is targeting an 8bit or 16bit microcontroller?

Comment: ATMEGA 328P-PU, so 8-bit. And as always i figured it out myself seconds after posting: I need to cast the 1 to a uint32_t...

Comment: Could probably also write it as `1UL`. C has suffixes which change the type of literals.

Comment: Thanks @ZanLynx, but that won't help much, because in reality i have to do things like this: `((uint32_t) ReadEeprom(address + 1) << 16)`

Comment: Why doesn't `ReadEeprom` return a `uint32_t` then?

Comment: Never mind, I see what you're doing. I would do explicit assignments to declared variables of the right size, but whatever works. Casting is just fine.

Comment: May you send a piece of code where we can see your issue? If you past a piece of code (also a function) we can better understand the problem.

Comment: Problem is solved, but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uint32_t b = 1 << 16;
```

as you noticed, this breaks down if you don't cast 1 to a 32-bit integer first:

The literal `1` is the default integer type on your compiler. Don't know which, but it's either an 8 or a 16 bit int.

Now, assume it's an 16 bit in. When you shift 1 left 16 times, you just... well, it doesn't make sense. So, make your `1` a 32 bit int first, then shift.

Comment: `int` is required to be at least 16 bits. No 8-bit into allowed.

Comment: A good way to go would be to use `UINT32_C(1)` from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to cast 1 to an uint32_t, so that there are enough bytes to shift it in.