# crc32 calculation in C produces different results on ATMEGA and Linux machines

Tags: c, cross-compiling, avr

I am sending messages from an ATMEGA644 to a Linux machine, and the CRC32 routine gives a different result on the two machines. The CRC algorithm is from [MIT](https://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/sys/libkern/crc32.c).

The ATMEGA version is compiled with avr-gcc and the Linux version with cc. The Linux compilation produces two warnings about the size of the printf parameters in the test harness, but even if you eliminate these warnings, the result is the same.

Here is the crc32 routine, together with a main() test harness that shows the problem:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
static const uint32_t crc32_tab[] = {
  0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f,
  0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
  0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2,
  0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
  0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9,
  0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
  0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b, 0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c,
  0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
  0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423,
  0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f, 0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
  0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d, 0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106,
  0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
  0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d,
  0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
  0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457, 0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950,
  0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
  0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2, 0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7,
  0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
  0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9, 0x5005713c, 0x270241aa,
  0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
  0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81,
  0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad, 0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
  0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683, 0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84,
  0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8, 0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
  0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb,
  0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7, 0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
  0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e,
  0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
  0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55,
  0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79, 0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
  0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f, 0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28,
  0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
  0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f,
  0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
  0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242,
  0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
  0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c, 0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69,
  0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45, 0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
  0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db, 0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc,
  0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
  0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693,
  0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf, 0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
  0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d
};

uint32_t crc32_le (uint32_t crc, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
  const uint8_t *p;
  uint32_t * tab_p;

  p = buf;
  crc = crc ^ ~0U;

  while (size--) {
    crc = crc32_tab[(crc ^ *p++) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);
  }

  return crc ^ ~0U;
}

void main (void) {
 char data [] = "{\n\"source\":  {\"device\":\"5A48A678AE25\", \"type\":63, \"utc\":21}, \n\"content\":  {\"function\":\"log\", \"data\":\"reset\"}\n}\n";

 printf ("lth=%d crc=%lx\n", strlen (data), crc32_le (0, data, strlen(data))); 

}
```

The programs output the following:

```
ATMEGA: lth=111 crc=da56a7aa
Linux: lth=111 crc=eda58ca9
```

I am at a loss to understand how this code can produce different results on different systems: any suggestions?

Comment: Try replacing `crc ^ ~0U` with `~crc` in the two places where it occurs, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: can you reproduce with a shorter string? Like, 1 or 2 characters? Would help to figure out what is happening

Comment: Do these machines have the same character set?  What if you output the entire string as hex pairs, and compare on the two platforms?

Comment: `0U`  likely defaults to an unsigned 8bit integer. ATMEGA is an 8bit machine. So, ~0U is 0xFF on ATMEGA.  But, on a 32 bit machine ~0U would be 0xffffffff.  So...use `~crc`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537051/avr-c-uint32-t-weird-behaviour

Comment: How does checksum XOR "all ones" even make sense? That's just obfuscation, use `crc = ~crc;`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey No, `0U` is of type unsigned 16 on ATMEGA. Integer constants cannot be smaller than `int` in C.

Comment: @Gerhard, it is conventional to define a function parameter as void * when it can handle any data type. If a caller wants the checksum of a struct, they need not know that this particular CRC32 implementation processes a byte at a time. memcpy is an example of a standard function that uses void * parameters.

Comment: @JavaLatte Because of alignment and aliasing rules you won't be able to implement it any differently than 1 byte at a time anyway. `const void*` actually just adds an uncertainty, a `const uint8_t*` would have been better. In fact the presence of `void*` in embedded systems code is often a sign of code smell.

Comment: Also it's an 8-bitter so it can't very well do it any other way... looking at the generated AVR assembly from all this 32 bit arithmetic makes me ill. Why people still insist on using 8-bitters, I have no idea.

Comment: @lundin crc32 is a bitwise polynomial. It can be implemented in many ways. but bytewise currently gives the best trade between memory usage and speed. As for 8 bit processors: for low cost/low power applications, you get more bang per buck/watt with 8 bit. This app is a downsize from a failed STM32 version that was a struggle to fit into 64k ROM. It now fits nicely into 32k ROM, and uses only 2mA instead of 10mA. As an IBM hardware engineer once aptly put it- imagine a texas drawl- "We hardware guys design more and more powerful machines, and you software guys just piss it all away".

Comment: @Lundin 8-bit parts are perfect for some applications.  This isn't one of them.

Comment: @JavaLatte Very few cores have bitwise instructions though, I don't believe AVR got them. It has to work on bytes.

Comment: @TomServo I ran out of the last argument for using 8-bitters around ten years ago. There are a whole lot of arguments against using one though, execution speed/high current consumption being the most obvious.

Comment: @TomServo You are doubtless familiar with the concept of a turing machine: a simple machine can emulate a more complex machine- it just takes longer. This app processes 1400 16-bit values per second, and does a CRC32 once per hour. The ATMEGA spends most of its time sleeping (0.19mA). The STM32 finished the job quicker, and so spends slightly more time sleeping (0.89mA).  The STM32 costs more and uses more current. The ATMEGA code generated by the compiler may be more complex, but it is nonetheless better suited to this application than the STM32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two different systems you are comparing have `int` types of different sizes, and although your code does not use `int` explicitly, it is used implicitly by the rules of the C language.

On the AVR, `~0U` has the type `unsigned int` (i.e. `uint16_t`) and a value of 0xFFFF.

On a normal PC, `~0U` has the type `unsigned int` (i.e. `uint32_t`) and a value of 0xFFFFFFFF.

Like Tom Karzes said, you should just use `~crc` if you want to invert all the bits in the `crc` variable in a simple, cross-platform way.